# Public cursor cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I am trying to get all the information a SQL database I created and display it in a listview however I am coming up against an error "cannot resolve symbol TABLE_NAME" even though it is defined as public static string at the top of the page.

```
public class database_helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";


public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "LASTNAME";


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + table);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: rebuild and try again.

Comment: p.s. your `insert();` won't work unless you wrap it in a transaction (and COMMIT the transaction). your code does an implicit ROLLBACK.

Comment: You need a space between "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" and the name of your table. (Currently, it will expand to: "DROP TABLE IF EXISTSentries_table".)

Answer (score 1):

`TABLE_NAME` is not a property of `COL_1`. Perhaps you meant

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access COL_1.TABLE_NAME as a parameter for db.query(). I'd suggest to remove `COL_1.`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a table.

just like this;

```
public class database_helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "testtable";

    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "LASTNAME";
}
```